# How to change object of object of array objects to array objects using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, arrayobject

I would like to know how to flatten the array of objects without flap map in javascript

If the of object of arrays object has length greater than 1, flatten

in my example `property black` has more than object so return that in array of objects

```
var obj ={
    "details": {
        "black": [
            {
            value: 100,
            name: "xxx"
            },
            {
            value: 200,
            name: "yyy"
            }
        ]
    },
    "sales": {
        "blue": [
            {
               value: 50,
               name: "abc"
            }
        ],
        "ALL": [
            {
              value: 20,
              name: "100"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Expected Output

```
[
  {
    value: 100,
    name: "xxx"
  },
  {
    value: 200,
    name: "yyy"
  }
]
```

have tried

```
const result = Object
    .values(obj)
    .flatMap(v => 
        Object.values(v as any)
            .filter((group: any) => group.length > 1)
    )
```

without flapmap how to do using javascript

Comment: Please fix the format of your question. There's text formatted as code that's clearly not code -> [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a recursive `flatten` function using `Array.reduce()` that takes a multidimensional array, and converts it to a flat array (TS playground):

```js
const obj = {"details":{"black":[{"value":100,"name":"xxx"},{"value":200,"name":"yyy"}]},"sales":{"blue":[{"value":50,"name":"abc"}],"ALL":[{"value":20,"name":"100"}]}}

const flatten = arr => 
  arr.reduce((acc, a) => acc.concat(
    Array.isArray(a) ? flatten(a) : a
  ), [])

const result = flatten(Object.values(obj)
  .map(v => 
    Object.values(v)
      .filter(group => group.length > 1)
  )
)

console.log(result)
```

**Note**: you can also use `Array.flat()` but since it came out with `Array.flatMap()` you would probably still have a compatibility problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj ={
    "details": {
        "black": [
            {
            value: 100,
            name: "xxx"
            },
            {
            value: 200,
            name: "yyy"
            }
        ]
    },
    "sales": {
        "blue": [
            {
               value: 50,
               name: "abc"
            }
        ],
        "ALL": [
            {
              value: 20,
              name: "100"
            }
        ]
    }
}

console.log(obj.details.black)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).